# Pytorch RNN prediction results do not match training results

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

The RNN code produces good sine approximations during traing, but when it comes to predicting sine values based in previous predictions (with a head start of 20 original values), it fails to approximate sine. (check images https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsJ3q.jpg)

So either there is a bug in the prediction code or the model in general is not capable of handling refeeded predictions. But I think its more of a bug in my code :)

Code:
https://gist.github.com/saschalippert/36b72313afff86e00f3e10254fb4ff25

Logs:

```
RNN(
  (rnn): RNN(1, 64, batch_first=True)
  (fc): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=1, bias=True)
)
Training for 10 epoch(s)...
Epoch:    1/10    Loss: 0.05084234103560448
Epoch:    2/10    Loss: 0.006296889390796423
Epoch:    3/10    Loss: 0.005784639157354832
Epoch:    4/10    Loss: 0.0037908838130533695
Epoch:    5/10    Loss: 0.0030788308940827847
Epoch:    6/10    Loss: 0.0027744979597628117
Epoch:    7/10    Loss: 0.0027218328323215246
Epoch:    8/10    Loss: 0.00589225348085165
Epoch:    9/10    Loss: 0.0020567490719258785
Epoch:   10/10    Loss: 0.000807589094620198
```

Answer (score 0):

Further testing showed that feeding the network with the predicted values (which have a slight deviation from the target values) cause to spiral the future values out of control. Using a more complex model and training for more episodes seems to solve the issue.